# How to get a specific point on a vector3 direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i could need some help with this problem:

I have a ball flying around in random directions. everytime he collides with something, he changes the direction.

i also have a player, for which i want to write a simple ai script. 
the player should go to the point, where he could meet the ball.

i made a simple picture for this problem in paint so that it's better to understand:

[image]

What i have is the yellow arrow, thats the ball's direction that it's moving. what i need is the red arrow direction for the player, but  i don't know how to do this?!

thanks for your help!!

Comment: Pick a point `p1` thats on the direction vector of the ball and calc a direction vector `dVP` for the player: `dVP = p1 - player.transform.position`. Now, since you didn't provide any specific info for the point other than being on the direction vector of the ball, we won't be able to say more than this.

Comment: Doesn’t the point where player and ball meet depend on their speed? There is probably more than one possible intersection point.

Comment: yes, the point depends on the speed of the ball. the speed of the player is inconsequential